# Chatter REST API Limit

Tags: chatter, rest, limits

Is there any way to increase the Chatter REST API limit of one poll per minute is a hard limit and cannot be increased?  We built a connected app using REST from a 3rd party portal application and hitting this limit with minimal user activity. We are using tokens as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are subject to 60/polls per minute per public/private messages per app per user. Your users should not ordinarily be hitting the limits as long as you follow the rules [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/intro_rate_limits.htm).

> - If you hit limits when running tests, use multiple users to simulate a real-world scenario.
> - When polling for feed updates, do not exceed one poll per minute (60 polls per hour). To return more results in 1 request, increase the
>     page size.
> - When polling for private messages, do not exceed 60 polls per hour.
> - To avoid making multiple requests, cache metered static assets such as file and dashboard renditions (group and user profile pictures are
>     not metered).
> - Each developer on a team should set up 2 connected apps: one for automated testing and one for manual testing and development. Don’t
>     share connected apps with other developers.
> - Use a unique connected app for the production environment.
> - Don’t share connected apps between applications.

Also, note that Session IDs are limited per user per hour, while OAuth tokens are limited per app per user per hour.

> For applications using a session ID from Salesforce, the rate limit is per user, per hour—there isn't a separate bucket for applications. All applications the user accesses with a session ID use this general quota. To take advantage of the per user, per application, per hour limit, use OAuth tokens.

These are hard limits, so you will have to work within those contexts.

Comment: We are using one integration account to get chatter feeds for all our 146 users. So that one account has the same limit of 60 polls per hour. Your info is interesting in that maybe we set up more than one connection point and balance the load across two channels?

Comment: The "per user" part; is that per user who is hitting the API, or per user license? i.e. if we have 100 user licenses do we get 6000 polls per minute per message per app?

Comment: @Mossi Updated the answer to reflect newer information (basically unchanged, but wording updated). It's *per user*, not *per user license*. Buying more licenses won't get you more limits. If one user exceeds their limits, other users can still continue to use Chatter.